# Python fluent filter, map, etc

Tags: python, functional-programming, fluent

I love python. However, one thing that bugs me a bit is that I don't know how to format functional activities in a fluid manner like a can in javascript.

example (randomly created on the spot): Can you help me convert this to python in a fluent looking manner?

```
var even_set = [1,2,3,4,5]
.filter(function(x){return x%2 === 0;})
.map(function(x){
    console.log(x); // prints it for fun
    return x;
})
.reduce(function(num_set, val) {
    num_set[val] = true;
}, {});
```

I'd like to know if there are fluid options? Maybe a library.

In general, I've been using list comprehensions for most things but it's a real problem if I want to print

e.g., How can I print every even number between 1 - 5 in python 2.x using list comprehension (Python 3 print() as a function but Python 2 it doesn't). It's also a bit annoying that a list is constructed and returned. I'd rather just for loop.

Comment: Just use a loop. Functional notation sends a strong signal that you're doing something without side effects, a signal you do not want to send for an operation like printing.

Comment: The answer is __don't__ use a comprehension to print. Comprehensions are a functional construct, as such, when people see a comprehension they are not expecting a side-effect.

Comment: You're having trouble because the example code you've provided does all sorts of non-functional things

Comment: fair enough. let's take out the map function and answer that question.... I think the 'map comprehension' that's introduced in some of the answers/comments below might actually be what I'm looking for. {y:True for y in xrange(1,6) if y % 2 == 0}.

Comment: Python users don’t like (or don’t care about) [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). They use function compositions everywhere (and there will be even more in future). They claim that fluent interface is non-functional (I disagree with this), so either forget about fluent interface, or use another language that works for fluent interface.

Comment: Python completely misses the boat on this.  Many of us are compelled to use the language in order to access the (_great_)  scientific, statistical, and plotting libraries. The language itself is broken in a fundamental way: it does not support chaining of collections operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators, iterators, and `itertools` give added powers to chaining and filtering actions.  But rather than remember (or look up) rarely used things, I gravitate toward helper functions and comprehensions.

For example in this case, take care of the logging with a helper function:

```
def echo(x):
    print(x)
    return x
```

Selecting even values is easy with the `if` clause of a comprehension.  And since the final output is a dictionary, use that kind of comprehension:

```
In [118]: d={echo(x):True for x in s if x%2==0}
2
4

In [119]: d
Out[119]: {2: True, 4: True}
```

or to add these values to an existing dictionary, use `update`.

```
new_set.update({echo(x):True for x in s if x%2==0})
```

another way to write this is with an intermediate generator:

```
{y:True for y in (echo(x) for x in s if x%2==0)}
```

Or combine the echo and filter in one generator

```
def even(s):
    for x in s:
        if x%2==0:
            print(x)
            yield(x)
```

followed by a dict comp using it:

```
{y:True for y in even(s)}
```

Comment: though not exactly a fluent interface. This seems to be the clearest option available

Comment: Python how-to on functional programming https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html

Answer (score 7):

**Update** Here's yet another library/option : one that I adapted from a `gist` and is available on `pipy` as `infixpy`:

```
from infixpy import *
a = (Seq(range(1,51))
     .map(lambda x: x * 4)
     .filter(lambda x: x <= 170)
     .filter(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 2)
     .filter( lambda x: x % 20 ==0)
     .enumerate()                                            Ï
     .map(lambda x: 'Result[%d]=%s' %(x[0],x[1]))
     .mkstring(' .. '))
print(a)
```

`pip3 install infixpy`

**Older**

I am looking now at an answer that strikes closer to the heart of the  question:

`fluentpy`  https://pypi.org/project/fluentpy/ :

Here is the kind of method chaining for collections that a `streams` programmer (in `scala`, `java`, others) will appreciate:

```py
import fluentpy as _
(
  _(range(1,50+1))
  .map(_.each * 4)
  .filter(_.each <= 170)
  .filter(lambda each: len(str(each))==2)
  .filter(lambda each: each % 20 == 0)
  .enumerate()
  .map(lambda each: 'Result[%d]=%s' %(each[0],each[1]))
  .join(',')
  .print()
)
```

And it works fine:

```
Result[0]=20,Result[1]=40,Result[2]=60,Result[3]=80
```

I am just now trying this out. It will be a very good day today if this were working as it is shown above.

**Update**: Look at this: maybe `python` can start to be more reasonable as one-line shell scripts:

```
python3 -m fluentpy "lib.sys.stdin.readlines().map(str.lower).map(print)"
```

Here is it in action on command line:

```
$echo -e "Hello World line1\nLine 2\Line 3\nGoodbye" 
         | python3 -m fluentpy "lib.sys.stdin.readlines().map(str.lower).map(print)"

hello world line1

line 2

line 3

goodbye
```

There is an extra `newline` that should be cleaned up - but the gist of it is useful (to me anyways).

Comment: fluentpy looks like the best answer to the question here. I'm surprised it's not more popular.

Answer (score 2):

Comprehensions are the fluent python way of handling filter/map operations.

Your code would be something like:

```
def evenize(input_list):
    return [x for x in input_list if x % 2 == 0]
```

Comprehensions don't work well with side effects like console logging, so do that in a separate loop.  Chaining function calls isn't really that common an idiom in python.  Don't expect that to be your bread and butter here.  Python libraries tend to follow the "alter state or return a value, but not both" pattern.  Some exceptions exist.

**Edit:** On the plus side, python provides several flavors of comprehensions, which are awesome:

List comprehension: `[x for x in range(3)] == [0, 1, 2]`

Set comprehension: `{x for x in range(3)} == {0, 1, 2}`

Dict comprehension: ` {x: x**2 for x in range(3)} == {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4}

Generator comprehension (or generator expression): `(x for x in range(3)) == <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10fc7dfa0>`

With the generator comprehension, nothing has been evaluated yet, so it is a great way to prevent blowing up memory usage when pipelining operations on large collections.

For instance, if you try to do the following, even with python3 semantics for `range`:

```
for number in [x**2 for x in range(10000000000000000)]:
    print(number)
```

you will get a memory error trying to build the initial list. On the other hand, change the list comprehension into a generator comprehension:

```
for number in (x**2 for x in range(1e20)):
    print(number)
```

and there is no memory issue (it just takes forever to run).  What happens is the range object gets built (which only stores the start, stop and step values (0, 1e20, and 1)) the  object gets built, and then the for-loop begins iterating over the genexp object.  Effectively, the for-loop calls

```
GENEXP_ITERATOR = `iter(genexp)`
number = next(GENEXP_ITERATOR)
# run the loop one time
number = next(GENEXP_ITERATOR)
# run the loop one time
# etc.
```

(Note the GENEXP_ITERATOR object is not visible at the code level)

`next(GENEXP_ITERATOR)` tries to pull the first value out of genexp, which then starts iterating on the range object, pulls out one value, squares it, and yields out the value as the first `number`.  The next time the for-loop calls `next(GENEXP_ITERATOR)`, the generator expression pulls out the second value from the range object, squares it and yields it out for the second pass on the for-loop.  The first set of numbers are no longer held in memory.

This means that no matter how many items in the generator comprehension, the memory usage remains constant.  You can pass the generator expression to other generator expressions, and create long pipelines that never consume large amounts of memory.

```
def pipeline(filenames):
    basepath = path.path('/usr/share/stories')
    fullpaths = (basepath / fn for fn in filenames)
    realfiles = (fn for fn in fullpaths if os.path.exists(fn))
    openfiles = (open(fn) for fn in realfiles)
    def read_and_close(file):
        output = file.read(100)
        file.close()
        return output
    prefixes = (read_and_close(file) for file in openfiles)
    noncliches = (prefix for prefix in prefixes if not prefix.startswith('It was a dark and stormy night')
    return {prefix[:32]: prefix for prefix in prefixes}
```

At any time, if you need a data structure for something, you can pass the generator comprehension to another comprehension type (as in the last line of this example), at which point, it will force the generators to evaluate all the data they have left, but unless you do that, the memory consumption will be limited to what happens in a single pass over the generators.

Comment: Generators have been promoted as a way chaining.

Comment: The OP ends up with a dictionary, so maybe `{x: True for x in input_list if x % 2 == 0}` is closer to his/her intention?

Comment: I actually did not know you could do 'map comprehensions' @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso that's actually really helpful!

Comment: @ThinkBonobo They're actually called dict comprehensions. You also have list and set comprehensions. Together they're one of my favorite features of Python.

Comment: I expanded my answer to talk about python's comprehension types and how they work.

Comment: Are there *really* no libraries in python to support fluent interface?  The above requires a bunch of additional intermediate variables.

Comment: This is not a fluent interface - which indicates arbitrarily long left to right chaining of collection operations.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest dealbreaker to the code you wrote is that Python doesn't support multiline anonymous functions. The return value of `filter` or `map` is a list, so you can continue to chain them if you so desire. However, you'll either have to define the functions ahead of time, or use a lambda.

Comment: single-expression lambdas are a good deal. I'm happy they don't support the OP's code. +1

Answer (score 1):

Arguments against doing this notwithstanding, here is a translation into Python of your JS code.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from functools import reduce

def print_and_return(x):
    print(x)
    return x

def isodd(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

def add_to_dict(d, x):
    d[x] = True
    return d

even_set = list(reduce(add_to_dict,
                map(print_and_return,
                filter(isodd, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])), {}))
```

It should work on both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: I guess in the end of the day I was hoping for a fluent style way of doing what you did in the last line. even skipping the print and return part of it. it'd be nice if it were something like '.filter(...).reduce(...)' that said, if it's not what python does it's not what it does. I was just curious

Comment: .. which shows the python really does not support in the intended fluent manner: needing to define the functions ahead of time is against the sense

Answer (score 1):

There's a library that already does exactly what you are looking for, i.e. the fluid syntaxt, lazy evaluation and the order of operations is the same with how it's written, as well as many more other good stuff like multiprocess or multithreading Map/Reduce.
It's named [`pyxtension`](https://github.com/asuiu/pyxtension) and it's prod ready and maintained on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pyxtension/).
Your code would be rewritten in this form:

```
from pyxtension.strams import stream
def console_log(x):
    print(x)
    return x
even_set = stream([1,2,3,4,5])\
    .filter(lambda x:x%2 === 0)\
    .map(console_log)\
    .reduce(lambda num_set, val: num_set.__setitem__(val,True))
```

Replace `map` with `mpmap` for multiprocessed map, or `fastmap` for multithreaded map.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder though about the comments that were given before where people were saying that fluent interfaces were not pythonic. does it still stand?

Comment: Actually chaining is very pythonic. Take the Guido van Rossum mail on chaining: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html
He's against sort to return self, but the chaining is basic python way to process strings like this:
y = x.rstrip("\n").split(":").lower()

Although, I disagree with Guido on the reasons against sort return self, that the reader shouldn't be familiar with each of the methods - otherwise how you intend to read the code if you're not familiar with methods?

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Pyterator](https://github.com/remykarem/pyterator) for this (disclaimer: I am the author).

We define the function that prints and returns (which I believe you can omit completely however).

```py
def print_and_return(x):
    print(x)
    return x
```

then

```py
from pyterator import iterate

even_dict = (
    iterate([1,2,3,4,5])
    .filter(lambda x: x%2==0)
    .map(print_and_return)
    .map(lambda x: (x, True))
    .to_dict()
)
# {2: True, 4: True}
```

where I have converted your reduce into a sequence of tuples that can be converted into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from streamable import Stream

event_set = set(
    Stream(lambda: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .filter(lambda n: n % 2 == 0)
    .foreach(print)
)
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...